# Help compiling (need old libs)

Tags: compiling, shared-library

I need to get a scientific software running but it requires older libs and I don't want to screw my current system.
I thought about using an old ubuntu version in a VM. But which would I need?

The software can be obtained [here](http://grail.cs.washington.edu/projects/photomontage/release/)

The Readme says:

> The Makefile assumes you are using wxWindows 2.4.2, and that it is
>   installed in /usr (/usr/lib/, /usr/include/wx, etc...).  It may,
>   however, be in /usr/local instead; in this case modify line 18 of the
>   Makefile appropriately.
>
> Also, wxWindows 2.4.2 has conflicts with very recent versions of GTK,
>   so you are welcome to use the most recent version of wxWindows
>   (2.6.0).  However, this would also require changing the Makefile,
>   namely lines 16-18.  Also, this new version of wxWindows splits the
>   libraries up into different parts; base, core, and gl.  You would need
>   to link to all these libraries.
>
> If you email me at aseem@agarwala.org, I can send you a Makefile
>   customized to 2.6.
>
> UPDATE: My code doesn't work with 2.6.  2.4.2 doesn't compile with
>   newer versions of g++.  So, this is a problem that I haven't had time
>   to fix.  Sorry.  You're only hope is to use an older g++.

Answer (score 5):

The real problem I see with the instructions you posted is that they ask for an older version of `g++`: installing a different library version is relatively simple, installing and running a different compiler is no small feat.  In addition, the instructions do not tell what version of g++ you should be using...

If I were to do this, I would proceed as follows:

1. As a [search in the Ubuntu package archive](http://packages.ubuntu.com) reveals, no Ubuntu version has wxWindows 2.4.2; *dapper* has 2.4.4, *hardy* and *jaunty* have 2.4.5.  This could be a compatible version (patchlevel numbers do not change the API) but one can only know by trying...
   They should have likely the correct g++ as well (since it was used to compile the Ubuntu package).
2. [Install](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/debootstrap) the [deboostrap](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/8/debootstrap) program, and use it to install a copy of an older Ubuntu in a directory `foo`:

   sudo deboostrap jaunty foo/
3. Download the sources and place them in some directory under `foo/`
4. Use [chroot](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/8/chroot) to get into the older environment and compile:

   ```
   $ sudo -s
   # chroot foo/
   (foo)# cd /source/directory; make
   ```

Note that, while in a chroot, you can only access files under `foo/` -- this has become the new *root directory* (just exit the shell to get back to normal).

You can also use a virtual machine instead of a chroot environment (replace steps 2., 4.); IMHO, chroots allow for more seamless usage although they can be a bit trickier to set up.